# android, ImageView bottom of screen

Tags: java, android, imageview

Trying to put a ImageView on the bottom of the screen, + a fit width.

Fit width are ok, but image are near half its height too lower.

A guess:  Are the Y of a Imageview centerBased?

Please don't profite "layout" solution, I look for a X, y, height, width solution. :)

(so simple in iOS )

```
private void layout_imageBottom(ImageView imageV) {


    imageV.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageV.setX(0);
    imageV.setMinimumHeight(imageV.getHeight());
    imageV.setMaxHeight(imageV.getHeight());
    Integer iS= Settings.getScreenSize(getApplicationContext()).x;
  imageV.setMinimumWidth(Settings.getScreenSize(getApplicationContext()).x);
    imageV.setMaxWidth(Settings.getScreenSize(getApplicationContext()).x);
    imageV.setY(Settings.getScreenSize(getApplicationContext()).y - imageV.getHeight());

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you set it like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)imageV.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

imageV.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but, ideally, I want to learn how to do it as a a X, y, height, width solution.

Comment: You can do it, but that's not the best practice in Android. Remember that iOS works differently.

Answer (score 0):

@Udi Idan was right, but if you still want to use X, Y, width, height solution then maybe you can try this

```
    int width = screenW;
    int height = 80;
    final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(width, height);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    layout.addView(imageView);

    imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            imageView.setX(0);
            imageView.setY(layout.getMeasuredHeight() - imageView.getMeasuredHeight()
                    - imageView.getPaddingBottom() - imageView.getPaddingTop());
        }
    });
```

P/S: I tried some codes like your sample and get the wrong result, maybe we need to calculate ActionBar's height. You could try.